# How to load my Facebook Friends from Facebook and display them on iPhone App? 

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I want the details about the friendlist like the below code

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMyFriends] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
            NSString *friendnames=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", user.friendsnames];
         }}];

}
```

can anyone please help with this code?

Comment: If you specify what kind of help you expect, someone certainly can.

Answer (score 6):

In my app I'm doing in this way:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,installed" andDelegate:self];

if ([request.url hasSuffix:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,installed"])
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in [result objectForKey:@"data"])
    {
        FacebookUser *friend = [[FacebookUser alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
        [array addObject:friend];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Hope it helps,
**Mário**

**EDITED:**

It's a model that I created, it implements NSObject

**FacebookUser.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FacebookUser : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *facebookID;
@property (readonly) NSURL *link;
@property (readonly) NSString *name;
@property (readonly) NSString *pictureURL;
@property (readonly) NSString *firstName;
@property (readonly) NSString *lastName;
```

**FacebookUser.m**

```
#import "FacebookUser.h"

@implementation FacebookUser

@synthesize facebookID = _facebookID;
@synthesize link = _link;
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize pictureURL = _pictureURL;
@synthesize firstName = _firstName;
@synthesize lastName = _lastName;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
    _facebookID = [dictionary valueForKey:@"id"];

    //IMPLEMENT WHAT YOU WANT TO SAVE.... 

    }

    return self;
}  

@end
```

Comment: Where to get this FacebookUser??

Comment: see what I added to this post

Comment: Can U please tell what is the [user objectForKey:] for the facebook user?

Comment: You want the information about the user that is logged in, right?